# textures with the backslash path is not loading the textures in OBJMTLLoder in firefox only

Tags: three.js

am using OBJMTLLoder to load the models am having the models with the textures inside the directory so my mtl file is as below

```
newmtl 15___Default
Ns 33.0000
Ni 1.5000
d 1.0000
Tr 0.0000
Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
illum 2
Ka 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
Kd 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
Ks 0.1710 0.1710 0.1710
Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
map_Ka maps\ed897c40.bmp
map_Kd maps\ed897c40.bmp
```

here the maps is the directory and it have the `ed897c40.bmp` textures, after load the model with the OBJMTLLoder it is working fine in the chrome, in the Firefox am getting

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://3dmodelviewer.osiztechnologies.com/threejs/examples/files/seaknight/maps%5Ced897c40.bmp"`

is it is a bug or how i deal with this ??

Comment: change the path to forward slashes `/`

Comment: we can change it manually for now, what about if the model is created like the above ?? so in three.js there is a function to read the textures there we can replace if the texture path contain \ and to /